# VSCode: Unable to write to Workspace Settings because no workspace is opened. Please open a workspace first and try again

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm programing a vscode(Visual Studio Code) extension, when I try to update a configuration like bellow code, I will get this error: `rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: Unable to write to Workspace Settings because no workspace is opened. Please open a workspace first and try again.`

My code:

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("myextention").update("myextention.conf", "231231223");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem.

The error means this:

A user using your extension must open a workspace where save configurations.

The workspace is not the one where you use for developing your extension.

---

You can see [How to store data for each "user" - VSCode Extention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963955/how-to-store-data-for-each-user-vscode-extention) for another way to save parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using the "Sync up" option of VS Code and using that from different computers (directly and through remote ssh).

The problem was about workspaces and different computers were being handled as different users.

The problem was solved by creating and saving a new workspace for each computer I was accessing the VS Code from.