# How to store data for each "user" - VSCode Extention

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making a extension for VSCode.

What method is generally to store data?
For example, settings for each user, not for each workspace.

I knew the way to store data in user's workspace.
But it is troublesome to set values for each workspace again and again.

Comment: store the value in the global `settings.json` this is different per user

Answer (score 1):

I've found a answer by myself.

ExtensionContext.globalState

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities

Code Sample(read and write)

```
function method_registerCommand(context){

    var store = context.globalState;
    store.update('user_name', 'Jhon').then(() =>{
        console.log(store.get('user_name'));
    });

}
```

or

```
function method_registerCommand(context){

    var store = context.globalState;
    store.update('user_name', 'Jhon');
    store.setKeysForSync(['user_name']);
    console.log(store.get('user_name'));
}
```

Comment: More specifically, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage
I was looking for https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext.globalStoragePath to store a file with my own format (but globalState is interesting too for small data).